# Como ordenar colunas da páginas com cliques

Tags: php, classificação

Preciso de uma grande ajuda com php. Sou novo em programação orientado a objetos, com ajuda de algumas pessoas tenho conseguido fazer um site onde trabalho de patrimônio, e tentado seguir umas regras de programação sempre que posso.

Tenho visto alguns exemplos de como ordenar colunas, mas não consigo colocar no meu, pois tenho procurado seguir conselhos de algumas pessoas na área de PHP e deixado meu site legalzinho, mas não vejo como colocar certo código dentro do meu, que são por meio de referência e parâmetros, mas certas coisas ainda tenho dificuldade ai da que parecer ser pouco, segue abaixo um pouco do meu código.

em views onde lista esta o seguinte list.php

```
<?php
// verificar se houve algum erro:
if ($sqli->error) {
// exibe o erro na tela:
die('<p class="error">Falha ao executar query: ' . $sqli->error . '</p>');
// fazer o procedimento de exibição apenas se houver resultado da busca acima
} elseif ($result->num_rows) {
// pegar todos os resultados em formato de array associativo
$dados = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
// linha de cabeçalho da tabela
$linha = '<tr><th>' . implode('</th><th>', array_keys($dados[0])) . '</th><th>Opções</th></tr>';
// percorrer os dados
foreach ($dados as $k => $v) {
// acrescenta outra linha
$v['nome'] = nl2br($v['nome']);
$linha.='<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>', $v) . '</td><td><input type="checkbox" title="Marque para excluir: ' . $v['nome'] . '" value=' . $v['id'] . ' name="sel[]">
<a href="?usuario/add/' . $v['id'] . '" title="Editar ' . $v['nome'] . '" class="edit"></a>
<a href="?usuario/list/'.$v['id'].'" title="Remover: '. $v['nome'].'" class="del"></a></td></tr>';
}
// mostra a linha na tela:
echo '<form method="post"><table class="tablesorter "><thead>'.$linha.'</thead><tr><td colspan="5"></td><td>';
?>
<input type="submit" value="Excluir marcados"
onClick="return confirm('Tem certeza de que deseja excluir os itens selecionados.\nATENÇÃO: os itens excluídos sãoo também desvinculados do banco de dados para as quais estão gravados.')">
</td></tr></table></form>
<?php

} else {
echo '<p class="warning">Nenhum registro encontrado!</p><a href="sql/install.php">Restaurar Database</a>';
}
?>
```

em controllers list.php

```
<?php
//apagar um
if(isset($PARAMS[0])){
$id = intval($PARAMS[0]);
$result = $sqli->query('DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE id='.$id);
if ($sqli->error) {
// exibe o erro na tela:
$msg[]='<p class="error">Falha ao deletar cadastro: ' . $sqli->error . '</p>';
} else {
$msg[]='<p class="ok">Remoção efetuada com sucesso!</p>'; 
}
}

// apagar vários
if (isset($_POST['sel'])) {
$result = $sqli->query('DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE id in(' . implode(', ', $_POST['sel']) . ')');
// verificar se houve algum erro:
if ($sqli->error) {
// exibe o erro na tela:
$msg[]='<p class="error">Falha ao deletar cadastro: ' . $sqli->error . '</p>';
}
}

$result = $sqli->query('SELECT id, nome, email, senha, situacoe_id,niveis_acesso_id,created, modified FROM usuarios order by id');
```

connect.php

```
<?php

// arquivo para conexão com o mysql
// definição de variáveis para conexão
$host = 'localhost'; // endereço do banco
$user = 'root'; // usuário
$pass = ''; // senha
$database = 'cad_user'; // nome do banco de dados

// se estiver em was
if (preg_match('/^(was)/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) {
$pass = '';
}

// estabelecer conexão:
$sqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass);

// verificando se conectou de boas:
if ($sqli->connect_error) {
// se houver alguma falha, exibe mensagem:
echo '<p class="error">Falha na conexão: ' . $sqli->connect_error . '</p>';
}

// definir o padrão de caracteres
if (!$sqli->set_charset('utf8')) {
// se não conseguir definir o padrão de caracteres, exibe o padrão disponível
echo "<p class='error'>Seu charset não é utf8!<br>$sqli->character_set_name()</p>";
}

// selecionar/abrir o banco de dados para trabalhar
if (!$sqli->select_db($database)) {
// se o banco de dados não for encontrado
if (!preg_match('/install.php/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
// ir para o arquivo de instalação do baco de dados, se já não estiver nele:
header('Location: sql/install.php');
}
echo "<p class='error'>Banco de dados não encontrado!</p>";
}
```

Tentei algumas forma de como ordenar como sugere o artigo [Tablesorter: Plugin jQuery para ordenar tabelas](https://www.todoespacoonline.com/w/2014/09/tablesorter-jquery/), mas não sei como ele não ordena, o código que coloquei esta sem as modificações que fiz.

Espero que me ajudem, pois ate agora ninguém me deu uma luz sobre isso.

Comment: Alguém aqui para me dar um help?